# Can I write "a technology-freed society" to mean "a society freed by technology"?

Tags: meaning

I'm writing a report and want to say "a society freed BY technology". Can I write "a technology-freed society" to mean that? Does it sound correct to a native speaker's ears? Or does "a technology-freed society" mean a society freed OF technology? Please help!

Comment: Only if you want it to be misunderstood.

Comment: You're likely to be misunderstood. I'm not going to endorse [a bug-freed environment](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2l_-VLPWFMfn7AbOn4DwCg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+bug-freed+environment%22) (used there to mean *an environment freed **of** bugs*, not ***by*** them). But that's what many people will assume you mean even in *writing*. They're practically *bound* to mis-hear if you ***say*** it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not suggest writing "a technology-freed society" to mean "a society freed by technology" unless the context is very clear. It's not incorrect, but it does share a meaning with "a society freed from technology", so you'd likely be causing your reader undue confusion. "A society freed by technology" is so nice and succinct already!